# How can I calculate the resistance-capacitance values in an analog computer model?

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, circuit-design, analog

[image]

This is the circuit design for this differential equation:

$$\frac{d^2V_o(t)}{dt^2}+2\frac{dV_o(t)}{dt}+11 V_o(t)=V_i$$

Capacitor and resistor values don't add up for this circuit. How should I change the capacitances to get an accurate model?

Comment: Is really 115k the "value" of the coefficient of 2*dVo/dt ... Should be 165k.

Comment: Time base is "330 kOhm*1 uF". Change the two capacitors "simultaneously" ... to 3.03 uF.

Answer (score 0):

Just choose the "time base" = 1 s (equal to: 330 kOhm * C).

So capacitors should be 1 s /330 kOhm = 3.03 uF.

[image]